# Необходимо отфильтровать список словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Дано 2 списка - список словарей и список с валидными ключами к нему. Необходимо вернуть список, в котором будут словари с первого, но только те, что имеют значения, которые не встречались раньше.
Импорт запрещен
Тоесть, если значения ключей из второго списка равны значению ключей из уже добавленного - словарь в список не добавляется
Пример:

```
origin = [
    {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
    {"foo": "F", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
    {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
]

result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["foo", "bar"])
# result -> [
#     {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
#     {"foo": "F", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
# ]
result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["foobar"])
# result -> [{"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"}]
result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["bar", "foobar"])
# result -> [{"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"}]
```

Если КЛЮЧЕЙ ДАНО НЕСКОЛЬКО смотрим на значения ВСЕХ (попарно). Из примера значения "foo" и "bar":
("FOO" "BAR") - добавляем, так как это первый
("F" "BAR") - добавляем, так как значения отличаются
(("FOO" "BAR") - не добавляем, так как эти значения были в первом словаре
Вот мой код:

```
def filter_by_first_met_value(dataset, keys):
    dataset1 = []
    dataset1.append(dataset[0])
    for x in keys:
        for y in dataset:
            if y.get(x) != dataset1[0].get(x):
                dataset1.append(y)
            else:
                continue
        return dataset1
```

Код работает, НО вот такой комментарий по решению я получил: "Проверяешь по одному значению вместо того, чтобы смотреть сразу за всеми. Такой подход будет срезать словари, которые не должны были быть отфильтрованы."

Как это исправить ? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_by_first_met_value(origin, keys):
    res = []
    exceptions = dict()
    for d in origin:
        is_passed = False
        for key in keys:
            if d.get(key, None) not in exceptions.get(key, set()):
                is_passed = True
            exceptions[key] = exceptions.get(key, set()) | {d.get(key)}
        if is_passed:
            res.append(d)
    return res

origin = [
    {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
    {"foo": "F", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
    {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
]

result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["foo", "bar"])
print(result==[
     {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
     {"foo": "F", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"},
 ])

result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["foobar"])
print(result==[{"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"}])
result = filter_by_first_met_value(origin, ["bar", "foobar"])
print(result==[{"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "foobar": "fb"}])
```

Comment: Сори, изменил условие, нужно сравнивать все ключи из второго списка вместе (сам далеко не сразу понял